# How to uninstall git from Ubuntu 16.04 without affecting packages dependent on it?

Tags: apt, package-management, git

@Team, 
I have git 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3 installed, I can see NESSUS scan on my device reports Critical Vulnerability with it.
Actually I don't need git in my device, I want to remove it, but issue is if there are packages dependent on it, then how to manage the situation,
Please do help.

Thanks in Advance,
Kamal

Comment: You didn't provide CVE specifics, but have you checked that your system has received all the patches? (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/).  If the packages were installed because of the install of `git` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/git) that's easily changed, however you've given no details on which packages are at concern (*that would influence what I'd opt to correct with*).

Comment: If you installed `git` using `apt` or `apt-get`, you can simply uninstall it including all dependencies. Dependencies are only uninstalled if they are not needed by other software.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the repositories settings on your system first. Thanks to Nessus, it warns you about this sysadm fault.

The correct `/etc/apt/sources.list` for *xenial* looks like:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

The latest version of git package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is [2.7.4-0ubuntu1.8](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/git), which is secure.
There was [USN for it](https://usn.ubuntu.com/4329-1/).

Carefully check/edit your repositories and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

to get all newest updates.

And of course you can remove git by

```
sudo apt-get remove git
```

if you (or `git`'s dependencies) do not need `git` anymore.